# Trying to get pyodbc as an include in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: python-3.x

how to get microsoft visual studio to recognize pyodbc as an include

I've used pip install and it worked but Visual Studio 2022 does not resolve the import, what am I doing wrong? where do I need to put the pyi and pyd files or am I just a lost cause?

Answer (score 0):

I had to move the whl from the scripts folder to the main folder (in my case python312) and use the -m switch for python.exe (python.exe -m pip install pyodbc-5.0.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl) and that installed it. Before I had the whl in the scripts folder and was running the script with ./pip install etc and that "installed it" but it didn't install it. I now have full access to pyodbc